# cedet automately open the header file for parsing, but not close it

Tags: emacs, cedet

when I compile the cedet ans use it to browse a c++ file, I find the lots error like following, and lots of header files are opened automately:

```
  Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer rtsp.cpp> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer QTSServer.cpp> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer main-handler.cpp> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer common.cpp> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer QTSSRollingLog.cpp> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer byteorder.h> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer c++locale.h> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer postypes.h> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer cwchar> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Mark set [12 times]
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer QTSServer.cpp> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer main-handler.cpp> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer common.cpp> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer QTSSRollingLog.cpp> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer byteorder.h> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer c++locale.h> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer dirent.h> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer cache.h> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer little_endian.h> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Idle Work Including Error: "#<buffer clocale> - Wrong type argument: stringp, (lambda (f) t)"
Mark set [6 t
```

I download the emacs from GNU ftp of versions 23.4 and compile and use it. But there is an old emacs in my system that I can't remove it due to some reason, I hope this old version will not affected. What's more, I have use the option "make EMACS=" to comple the cedet-1.1.
Pls help me to solve this problem, it confuse me so long a time.

Comment: The latest released version of Emacs is 24.2. You should at least try that first.

Comment: Have tried that, the result remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get errors  from the idle work handler, start with:

```
M-x semantic-debug-idle-work-function RET
```

to  get a full stack of what is going on.  That will point you toward the issue.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I fix it out.